# How to call a VueJS getter from browser console?

Tags: vue.js, debugging

I have a VueJS component that I'd like to debug. I need to check the behaviour of a getter in the browser. Is it possible to call it manually from the browser console?

**Edit**: This link contains some info on how to trigger a state change manually: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/forcing-a-refresh-to-a-getter/32922

Especially:

> a mutation update to a state collection such as:
>
> ```
> state.items = {}
> ```
>
> in mutations:
>
> ```
> state.items[item.key] = item // does not trip off detection
> ```
>
> instead use this
>
> ```
> Vue.set(state.items, item.key, item) // this does trip detection.
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing this:

- Use [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools). You can see Vuex store there in the `Vuex tab`, so you can do some debugging visually.
- Or make Vue available globally `window.App = new Vue(....))`. You will be able to get Vue instance as `window.App`
- Or, as it was suggested in the comments, you could run `console.log(this.$state.getters)` somewhere in the app, then in the console right click on that output and click "Store as global variable" which will make it available as `temp1`. Then you can access it as `temp1.someGetterName`

Comment: Thank you Alex, but it's not obvious for me how to call a getter from the dev tools. I'm testing your second solution.

Comment: Second question: It seems like the getters are reduced to values at some point. Is there a way to recalculate them?

Comment: Add this one too: console.log() everything you need like `console.log(this.$state.getters)` where you need then right click on what console.log returned and click on `Store as global variable`, data will be store in variable name `temp1` and you can manipulate or view it

Comment: @OlleHärstedt vue-devtools is more for visual debugging, it shows you how things change and what changes what. As for recalculating getters, what do you mean by that? I think getters are supposed to always return what you specified in them, I'm not sure what kind of recalculation you are talking about, e.g.if you create a getter "selectedItems" that `return state.someArray.filter(item => item.isSelected)` it will always do exactly that and if you need to return something else, just create another getter.

Comment: @AlexHoffman OK, you're saying that if the state changes, all getters are run automatically?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt yes, that's the magic of Vue! Everything updates automatically. That's why I use Vue in all my projects now, it reduces the amount of work significantly

Comment: @AlexHoffman I will try to use jest to debug the getter, since we already use jest in our project. Thanks for you feedback! I will mark it as resolved.